# Storing each part of a split string?

Tags: java

I have split a string, but how can i put each split part into its own string?
Example: One of the split parts will be say: `220532` how would i put it into its own string so i can use it later on? I have been searching around quite a bit and i haven't found anything to help me, maybe i am looking in the wrong place, i don't know.

My a section of my code (splitting code):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String delim = (", ");
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("225433,1690,29040474 267067,77,1529611     
    237690,78,1788405 273749,79,1854885 274972,79,1952641 268946,71,867189 239419,64,420791 
    238742,81,2319417 159198,85,3530900 138028,90,5475735 208678,78,1696957 174967,79,1869053 
    290115,65,469553 212042,65,486662 359576,48,84972 201637,70,790755 240043,55,167763 
    282705,52,132888 244545,56,198147 261757,56,201357 281466,39,34650 239398,57,214448 
    100420,76,1347559 250011,51,115880 144608,72,912505 166813,67,577751 -1,1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 
    -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 73106,748 -1,-1 -1,-1 92834,659 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 
    -1,-1", delim);

    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        System.out.println(st.nextToken());
     }

}
});
```

Comment: Yeah it works perfectly, try it just before you insult my code. :)

Comment: `String token1 = st.nextToken();` ... Why not use `String.split()` for this?

Comment: Have you considered using an array?  Or one of the array-like objects such as ArrayList?

Comment: As noted in the Javadocs for `StringTokenizer`, it really shouldn't be used in new code. `String[] array = yourString.split(",|\\s");` Done.

Comment: @BrianRoach it will work partially, because then on the output will be empty signs. Try this: `String[] splittedText = new String("2, 23, 45, 56, 567").split(",|\\s");
        for(String s : splittedText)
            System.out.println(s);`

Comment: Erm, correct ... it wouldn't work for your example array, which has absolutely nothing to do with the OP's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an list of Strings and add each token to it.

```
ArrayList<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
while(st.hasMoreTokens())
{
   myStrings.add(st.nextToken());
}
```

Now `myStrings` contains all of the individual strings you split from the longer one.

EDIT: Then to access them, you can use a for-each loop (or a standard for loop).

```
for(String number : myStrings)
{
    System.out.println(number);
    //sample output: "225433"
    //               "1690"
}
```

or

```
for(i = 0; i < myStrings.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println("Number " + i + " is: " + myStrings.get(i));
    //example output: "Number 0 is: 225433"
    //                "Number 1 is: 1690"
}
```

The former is more concise, but if you want to know the index of the element you're working with then the latter is necessary.

And if you just want the first element, that's at `myStrings.get(0)`

Comment: I think this is what i need, if not i will say later. Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering, because the numbers will be changing very often, how could i use them, EG `System.out.prinln("first number: +FIRSTNUMBER);`   how can i get FIRSTNUMBER to be the first number from the array?

Comment: @WillBaker I've added that to an edit of my answer.

Comment: this is returning all of the numbers, what if i want just one? An example could be that i have a label: `label = new JLabel("This is the first number of my string:"+firstnumber);` (+firstnumber, will probably be completely different code, but you get the idea?

Comment: If you only want one, you need to know its index and call `myStrings.get(index)`. The first one is of course at index 0, so `String first = myStrings.get(0)` would result in `first` containing the value of the first string. Though of course you would want to be sure these indexes actually exist before trying to retrieve their values, as if the index is >= `myStrings.size()` or negative then you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a String like

```
String number="1,2,3,4,5";
String num[]=number.split(","); //This statement split the number using delimiter ","
               //means num[0]="1",num[1]="2" and so on..
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store each piece in a `List` (part of the [Java Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) framework)...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String delim = ", ";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("225433,1690,29040474 267067,77,1529611 237690,78,1788405 273749,79,1854885 274972,79,1952641 268946,71,867189 239419,64,420791 238742,81,2319417 159198,85,3530900 138028,90,5475735 208678,78,1696957 174967,79,1869053 290115,65,469553 212042,65,486662 359576,48,84972 201637,70,790755 240043,55,167763 282705,52,132888 244545,56,198147 261757,56,201357 281466,39,34650 239398,57,214448 100420,76,1347559 250011,51,115880 144608,72,912505 166813,67,577751 -1,1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 73106,748 -1,-1 -1,-1 92834,659 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1",
                    delim);
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        parts.add(st.nextToken());
    }
    for (String s : parts) {
        // Do something with s
    }
}
```

Or you can use something like [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String delim = ", ";
    String input = "225433, ....";
    String[] parts = input.split(delim);
    for (String s : parts) {
        // Do something with s
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for helping the poster *and* providing a useful alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
String[] splittedText = new String("your text").split(",\\s+|\\s+|,");
```

It will split, if there is a space, or coma and space. It will work for your numbers.

Example:

```
String[] splittedText = new String("225433,1690,29040474 267067,77,1529611     237690,78,1788405 273749,79,1854885 274972").split(",\\s+|\\s+|,");
        for(String s : splittedText)
            System.out.println(s);
```